# Struggling to make sense of an array

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to make the transition from PHP to ruby(finally).  I am attempting to complete the rubymonk challenges but I am stuck on the third challenge.

The challenge itself is easy and I've already found a solution, but I cant figure out what type of data I'm looking at or how to process it properly.

The challenge simply wants you create a method that takes a array containing some strings, and return a count of each string in that same position.  so ["I","suck","at","ruby"] == ["1","4","2","4"].

That part is Ez-pz, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to process the input properly.

It gives you a shell of method and tells you to complete it

```
def lenght_finder(input_array)
   #I added the print input_array
   print input_array #=> ["I","am","genius"]["things","are","","awesome"]
end
```

Is this a multidimensional array?
I've tried to replicate this in IRB with

```
input_array = ["I","am","genius"]["things","are","","awesome"]
```

but it returns and error

```
input_array = [["I","am","genius"],["things","are","","awesome"]]
```

works, but that is clearly not that same.
Because of this I am struggling to traverse the array to process that data properly.
I can't get anything like `input_array.flatten` to work, or `input_array[0]` which returns "Ithings".

This is confusing me. Am I looking at a single array? a multidimensional array? Clearly it cant be a string. Why does it skip "am" when accessing `input_array[0]`?

Comment: In your definitions of `input_array`, you have a single quote starting "genius" and a double-quote ending it.  Hopefully just a typo...

Comment: I believe the two arrays are meant to be two different test cases. At least that is what I saw when I attempted the [challenge](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/5-string-length-finder).

Comment: Congratulations for changing to ruby :) In such cases it is always useful to debug your program. Put the `debugger` (or `pry`) line at the top of your method and inspect your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha, like Justin Ko suggested in his comment above, what you're seeing is the stdout of running the function twice.

Since you used `print`, there's no newline.  Use `puts` instead.

This should help you see it more clearly:

```
def length_finder(input_array)
   puts '*** '+input_array.inspect
   return 0
end
```